# Library Access/Usage Statistics in SharePoint Foundation 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, logging

Is it possible to obtain usage statistics in SharePoint Foundation 2013? Say for example, if I want to see how many times a PDF in a library, or a list item has been accessed over a period of time, and by who?

I know that the OOTB logging in 2013 has been trimmed down, and foundation is always significantly limited in this regard. Can I directly poll the WSS_Logging database for this information? If so, is there any good resources on doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Usage Events - Every time that a user views an item, the system issues a usage event.In SharePoint 2013 three usage events are defined out of the box . These default events are always registered and analyzed by SharePoint.

Following are the default usage events

Views – number of views for a single item, page, or document.

Recommendations Displayed – number of times a single item, page or document was displayed as a recommendation.

Recommendation Clicks – number of times a single item, page or document was clicked when it was displayed as a recommendation.

Custom Events - In addition to the default events, you can add up to twelve custom events. For example, you can add a custom event that tracks how often an item is accessed from a mobile platform or How often someone Liked a Conversation.

Comment: How do I access the data behind these usage events? The Log DB?